# Using Zend_Controller_Router_Route to create friendly URLs for the actions in IndexController

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-controller-router

In my IndexController, I currently have indexAction (homepage), loginAction and logoutAction.  I'm trying to remove "/index/" from the URL to get domain.com/login instead of domain.com/index/login.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?  Is there a RegEx we can use?  I don't ever want /index/ in the URL.

My current solution, which I believe can be improved upon, is below.  Also, what does the first parameter in addRoute() do?

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
  protected function _initViewHelpers()
  {
    $front  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute('login',
      new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('login/*', array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'login'
      ))
    );
    $router->addRoute('logout',
      new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('logout/*', array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'logout'
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to impove, you have to create route for every action. This will allow you to change route defaults (module/controller/action) without modifying your code.

First parameter is the route name, which you have to use with url() helper in your views:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(), 'login', true); ?>">Login</a>
```

Update. You can use such route, if you want only one route without "index" in url:

```
$router->addRoute('default',
  new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':action/*', array(
    'controller' => 'index',
  ))
);
```

Comment: I can't use that because I'm using Zend_Navigation to manage the links.  I'm looking for a way to use a RegEx so that I only have to use addRoute() once.

Comment: I updated my answer. BTW what's the problem with Zend_Navigation?

Comment: Thanks!  That worked except I had to change the 1st param for addRoute() from 'default' to 'index' otherwise my URL ended up as domain.com/index/controller/login.  There's no problem with Zend_Navigation, what I meant was I'm not building the hyperlinks myself, I'm simply printing $this->navigation()->menu(); from my layout.